# DataTables con idioma ingles y semantic-ui

Tags: javascript, datatables, semantic-ui

Estoy tratando de implementar esta herramienta que encontré que me parece absolutamente maravillosa: 
[Data Tables + Semantic UI](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/semanticui.html)

Ahora bien, descargue los js y los css de referencia, y sigo viendo las partes de la tabla en inglés. Quiero aclarar que edité el archivo jquery.dataTables.min.js y reemplacé todos los items que figuraban en inglés y aún sigue mostrandome todo en inglés:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

SOLUCION

---

GRACIAS AL APORTE DEL AMIGO QUE ME ORIENTÓ, me pasó un código que en realidad no funcionó en el ejemplo, pero busqué en la documentación del sitio y encontré algo que sí funcionó:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tabla').DataTable({
      language: 
      {
        "sProcessing":     "Procesando...",
        "sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
        "sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron resultados",
        "sEmptyTable":     "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
        "sInfo":           "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
        "sInfoEmpty":      "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
        "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
        "sInfoPostFix":    "",
        "sSearch":         "Buscar: ",
        "sUrl":            "",
        "sInfoThousands":  ",",
        "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
        "oPaginate": {
          "sFirst":    "Primero",
          "sLast":     "Último",
          "sNext":     "Siguiente",
          "sPrevious": "Anterior"
        },
        "oAria": {
          "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
          "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
        }
      }
      });
    });
</script>
```

ahora subo una imagen de cómo quedó:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No deberías cambiar/editar el código de una biblioteca que te descargaste de Internet. Si por cualquier motivo luego otra persona sigue el proyecto, puede asumir erróneamente que las bibliotecas son las estándar y encontrarse con errores que no tienen explicación.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque el OP solucionó el problema, pero incluyó la respuesta en la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El idioma lo puedes cambiar cuando declaras el Datatable con la propiedad `language`

quedando el código algo así: **(estas solo son algunas propiedades si deseas cambiar iconos u otras propiedades mas ve [este enlace](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language))**

```
var table = $('#DataTablesClientes').DataTable({
    language: {
        "decimal": "",
        "emptyTable": "No hay información",
        "info": "Mostrando _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ Entradas",
        "infoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 to 0 of 0 Entradas",
        "infoFiltered": "(Filtrado de _MAX_ total entradas)",
        "infoPostFix": "",
        "thousands": ",",
        "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ Entradas",
        "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
        "processing": "Procesando...",
        "search": "Buscar:",
        "zeroRecords": "Sin resultados encontrados",
        "paginate": {
            "first": "Primero",
            "last": "Ultimo",
            "next": "Siguiente",
            "previous": "Anterior"
        }
    },
    ....
});
```

> **Recomendación:**
>   Te sugiero nunca editar los archivos de terceros a menos que la licencia lo permita, de lo contrario es mejor implementar una función que haga esos cambios que deseas quedando en claro que este no implementa un método o propiedad para hacer dicho cambio

Comment: OK... genial, buen punto... voy a ver si lo descargo nuevamente... no sabía esa posibilidad... muchas gracias !!!

Comment: trato de implementarlo y no me funciona... lo coloco en el script para llamar al javascript pero si le coloco la opción del lenguaje, no aplica el proceso... LISTO LISTO... BUSQUE EL CODIGO EN LA PAGINA DE ELLOS Y SI ME ANDUVO... VOY A PONER LA SOLUCION EN LA ENTRADA POR SI A ALGUIEN LE SIRVE

Comment: Puedes agregar como lo haces, en tu pregunta, omite los puntos.